# JS page display depending on URL

Tags: javascript, css, hashtag

I have a site that loads all the content in one file and then changes all divs style to `display:none` apart from the one selected from the menu.

What I would like is to be able to add a hash to the url that would then point to one of the divs and hide all the others like what happens when the menu buttons are clicked.

View the site along with JS, CSS and HTML here: http://jsfiddle.net/5vL2LjLe/2/

This is the JavaScript I started to add to check if the URL contained certain text:

```
//shows page depending on url
$(document).ready(function() {
    if(window.location.href.indexOf("#lgc") > -1) {
       console.log("#lgc");
    }
    else if(window.location.href.indexOf("#webcams") > -1) {
       console.log("#webcams");
    }
    else if(window.location.href.indexOf("#rasp") > -1) {
       console.log("#rasp");
    }
    else if(window.location.href.indexOf("#charts") > -1) {
       console.log("#charts");
    }
    else if(window.location.href.indexOf("#dunstablepara") > -1) {
       console.log("#dunstablepara");
    }
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, you're using a function to show and hide the DIVs that is defined when setting the event listener. However, what you are wanting to do is basically have the same effect nominating (e.g. by name) the section you want to show or hide.

One way to do this is to create a function where you can provide the ID prefix, and it will hide and show the relevant parts of the page. The following is basically derived from your existing 'menu-clicker' handler.

```
function switchToDiv(idprefix) {
  var navItem = $('#' + idprefix + '-link'),
      pageDiv = $('#' + idprefix + '-page');

  if (!(navItem.hasClass('active'))) {
    //hide other pages and show the linked one
    $("div[id*='-page']").hide();
    pageDiv.show();

    //set all links inactive and the clicked on active
    $("li[id*='-link']").removeClass("active");
    navItem.addClass("active");
  }
}
```

The second part is how you trigger that function. Your code has a set of 'if' statements in an anonymous function called by *$(document).ready*.
First, because you are basically doing a set of string comparisons, a switch statement is better suited. Also, because you may want to use the function at other times, it is probably worth giving it a name.

```
function loadPageFromHash() {
    switch (window.location.hash) {
        case '#lgc':
            switchToDiv('lgcweather');
            break;
        case '#rasp':
            switchToDiv('rasp');
            break;
        case '#charts':
            switchToDiv('charts');
            break;
        case '#dunstablepara':
            switchToDiv('dunstablepara');
            break;
        case '#webcams':
            switchToDiv('webcam');
            break;
       default:
            // do anything you need to in order to load the home page
    }
}
```

Finally, you can call that function when the page loads, *and* when the hash of the URL changes if that is desirable.

```
//shows page depending on url
$(document).ready(loadPageFromHash);
$(window).on('hashchange',loadPageFromHash);
```

An alternative to the 'switch' statement is to use a dictionary to map the URL # text to a 'prefix', for example:

```
function loadPageFromHash() {
    var mappings = {
      '#lgc': 'lgcweather',
      '#rasp': 'rasp',
      '#charts':'charts',
      '#dunstablepara':'dunstablepara',
      '#webcams':'webcam'
    }
    if (window.location.hash in mappings) {
        switchToDiv(mappings[window.location.hash]);
    } else {
        //special case for home
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that with the function written as above, the mappings dictionary is created every time. This will certainly be less efficient than the switch statement, although arguably neater.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `location.hash` instead of `location.href`.

W3Schools: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp

Comment: The location.href isn't the issue here.  I want it to only show a certain div depending on what hash is in the url.

Comment: I kinda misread the question, and frankly I even thought the `location.href` excluded the hash from the url. Regardless, the correct approach in this case would be to use `location.hash` instead (as it is really the only thing you are checking against). That way you can also drop the .indexOf().